# iOS - App Clips with IBM Mobile First Integration

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, xcode12, mfp

**Background:**

I have an iOS App using IBM Mobile First.

**Issue:**

I want to use App clips using one service by following [this MFP guide](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/hello-world/configuring-a-native-ios-application-with-the-mfp-sdk/) but it's crashing while I'm calling the service, and showing this error:

```
2020-08-18 10:47:51.906014+0400 (App Name)[30727:3766051] -[__NSDictionaryI WLJSONRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600003a82900
```

Your support will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App Clips haven't been validated and supported by the Mobile Foundation SDK yet. Open an enhancement request [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=144334)